# How do I only search in Leads using searchAndScreenPop()?

Tags: lightning, community, search, opencti, global-search

The search API by default searches in Contacts, Leads, Accounts, etc. I want to limit it to either one because the user may not have privileges to Contacts or Accounts in this instance. The search API throws an error in this scenario and doesn't return a single record.

> ui.services.connection.api.PartnerConnectionException: INVALID_FIELD:
> IsConverted = false LIMIT 200), Contact(AccountId, IsPersonAccount, Name
>                        ^ERROR at Row:1:Column:87
> No such column 'AccountId' on entity 'Contact'.
> If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: I assume you're referring to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_searchandscreenpop_lex.htm) call. Could you add your exact call with parameters to the question?

Comment: Yes that's the call i'm talking about. I'm just passing the number as a searchParam. I wanted to know if I can add filters to the search. Like only searching in Leads or Contacts and not through the entire salesforce list. The agents only have access to Leads resulting in the search failing.